# How can I simplify this step by step?

Tags: fractions

I want to simplify this :

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2} + \frac{(x\tan \theta)^2}{b^2} = 1$$

The answer is supposed to be this :

$$x = \frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2+a^2\tan^2 \theta}}$$

I’d like to understand this step by step

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: i have reach this , dont know it's right or wrong 

x^2 = ( a^2*b^2 - a^2*x^2*tanθ^2  )/b^2

Comment: You're going to want to isolate $x$ so that you can solve for it. You have $x$ on both sides right now, which will make your job much harder.

Comment: @ruruarchy Please check out how to use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). Using formatting allows your text to be read more easily.

Comment: alright , i'll check that , it's my first time to be here :)

Comment: Remark: you're not simplifying (okay, maybe), but instead solving for $x$.

Comment: i find it simpler, but yes, you were right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Begin by rewriting the first equation as: $$x^2\left(\frac{1}{a^2} + \frac{\tan^2\theta}{b^2} \right) = 1$$
You can then take a common denominator to get: $$x^2\left(\frac{b^2 + a^2\tan^2\theta}{a^2b^2} \right) = 1$$
Divide out to isolate $x$:
$$x^2 = \frac{a^2b^2}{b^2 + a^2\tan^2\theta} $$
And finally, take the square root of both sides (actually, there should be both positive and negative solutions to this equation, as we began with $x^2$; both the positive and negative values are legal):
$$x = \pm \frac{ab}{\sqrt{b^2 + a^2\tan^2\theta}} $$
As long as this is well-defined.

Comment: thank you very much :) , this is really helpfull i'll try to understand this one by one